# Why using " select count " gets less number of duplication rows than the real number

Tags: mysql, duplicates, left-join

I have this table with 6735 rows, like this:

```
id title source_link date_created processed topic_id date_create_unix
```

it has several rows with duplicate "title", some rows duplicated 2 times, some 3 or 4 times. So I have to delete the extra rows, but to do that, I have to delete the rows at link table first (else it will not allowed me to delete due to foreign key constraints). So I need to extract the id of the extra rows.
I can get the id(s) of the rows I want to keep by:

```
    SELECT t1.id FROM Data.rss_table t1
INNER JOIN Data.rss_table t2 
WHERE 
    t1.id > t2.id AND 
    t1.title = t2.title
```

it gives me 1350 rows.

Then if I use this:

```
SELECT t1.id FROM Data.rss_table t1
INNER JOIN Data.rss_table t2 
WHERE  
    t1.id != t2.id
AND
    t1.title = t2.title
```

it will give me 2700 rows. So I know that it does not contain all the duplication id, because some rows duplicate more than twice, so the number should be more than 1350 x 2 (=2700).

So I hope this will give me all the duplication:

```
SELECT * FROM Data.rss_table GROUP BY title HAVING COUNT(title) > 1
```

but it returns only 944 rows. I am very surprise by this result, it even smaller than the result from 2nd query above (2700). While I thought it should give all rows with duplicated title, so the number should be larger.
How to explain this, and how could I archive my results ?

Note: If the second query give me all the ID of the duplications rows I can delete the link table by this query:

```
Delete from Data.rss_source_link where rss_id in (
Select SetA.id from (SELECT t1.id FROM Data.rss_table t1
INNER JOIN Data.rss_table t2 
WHERE  
    t1.id != t2.id
AND
    t1.title = t2.title) as SetA
left join 

(SELECT t1.id FROM Data.rss_table t1
INNER JOIN Data.rss_table t2 
WHERE 
    t1.id > t2.id AND 
    t1.title = t2.title) as SetB
On SetB.id = null
);
```

Comment: Why is title alone not enough to define duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Its' easy to produce the effect you are seeing

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t(id int, title varchar(3));
create table t1(id int,title varchar(3));

insert into t values
(1,'aaa'),(1,'aaa'),(2,'aaa');

insert into t1 values
(1,'aaa'),(1,'aaa'),(2,'aaa');

SELECT t1.id ,t2.id
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t1 t2
WHERE 
    t1.id > t2.id AND 
    t1.title = t2.title;

+------+------+
| id   | id   |
+------+------+
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT t1.id t2.id
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t1 t2 
WHERE  
    t1.id != t2.id
AND
    t1.title = t2.title;

+------+------+
| id   | id   |
+------+------+
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    2 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM t GROUP BY title HAVING COUNT(title) > 1;

+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaa   |
+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So what do you mean by duplicate - is it id+title or just title?

Comment: Only title is duplicate. Id is all unique and auto incremental ...

Comment: what you showed doesn't answer my question or help to explain anything. Can you explain a little bit more ?